# How to get last weeks data from mysql from friday to friday

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have a table which records for a ticket system. I want to get counts of all staff tickets between friday to friday of previous week. For example between : 11.08.2021 - 18.08.2021 What i tried is ;

```
    SELECT staffName,createdAt, staff, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM tickets t
WHERE (t.createdAt >=
      DATE_SUB(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK), INTERVAL 1 + DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE()) DAY)
  AND
      t.createdAt <
      DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL WEEKDAY(NOW()) + 3 DAY))
  AND open = 0
GROUP BY staffName
ORDER BY `count` DESC
```

But this query also pulls records older than 2 weeks. I don't want to see if there is no recording.

Comment: Why don't you just pass in 2 dates. Much easier that way.

Comment: Because date is always changing. Next week i will need this weeks data.

Comment: What do you mean by "last week"? On what day does the "week" start? Friday to Friday is 8 days, not 7.

Comment: Prev Friday to this Friday

Comment: I understand that the dates keep changing. But what I meant is that you get 2 dates with PHP for example, and use those in your sql commands. But I don’t know if you have access to PHP